# Elasticsearch: "reason": "failed to find geo_point field"

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I am  trying to sync mysql data (which changes dynamically) with `elasticsearch`. I am using `logstash` for the syncing purpose. I need to filter the list of vehicles in the radius of 1KM for the passed `geo_points`. While making a geo_point query on elasticsearch, I am getting error as:

```
{"error":
    {"root_cause": [
        {"type": "query_parsing_exception",
         "reason": "failed to find geo_point field [location]",
         "index":"current_location",
         "line":13,
         "col":9}
        ],
     "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
     "reason": "all shards failed",
     "phase":"query",
     "grouped": true,
     "failed_shards":[
         {"shard":0,
          "index": "current_location",
          "node":"Pf8eXXX2QMuaskBuLSdcXw",
          "reason": {
             "type":"query_parsing_exception",
             "reason":"failed to find geo_point field [location]",
             "index":"current_location",
             "line":13,
             "col":9}}
         ]},
"status":400}
```

`Curl` call that I am making is:

```
curl -XGET http://MY.ELASTIC.SEARCH.IP:9200/current_location/vehicle/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "geo_distance": {
        "distance":      "1km",
        "distance_type": "plane", 
        "location": {
          "lat":  40.715,
          "lon": -73.988
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}'

Result of curl call on any of the index is as:

```
curl -XGET http://MY.ELASTIC.SEARCH.IP:9200/current_location/vehicle/XX12XX34XX56
{
    "_index": "current_location",
    "_type": "vehicle",
    "_id": "XX12XX34XX56",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "obd_id": "XX12XX34XX56",
        "system_timestamp": 1464855810,
        "gps_timestamp": 1464855807,
        "speed": 1.476,
        "direction": 0,
        "latitude": 12.9699,
        "longitude": 77.7004,
        "@version": "1",
        "@timestamp": "2016-06-05T16:09:46.712Z",
        "type": "vehicle",
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9699,
            "lon": 77.7004
        }
    }
}
```

Content of my `logstash.conf` file is:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://MY.MYSQL.DB.IP:3306/my_db"
        jdbc_user => "MY_USER"
        jdbc_password => "MY_PASSWORD"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/moin/moin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT obd_id, system_timestamp, gps_timestamp, speed*0.036 as speed, direction, latitude/3600000.00 as latitude, longitude/3600000.00 as longitude from current_location"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => system_timestamp
        add_field => {"type" => "vehicle"}
    }
}
filter {
  if [latitude] and [longitude] {
    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "[location][lat]" => "%{latitude}"
        "[location][lon]" => "%{longitude}"
      }
    }
    mutate {
      convert => {
        "[location][lat]" => "float"
        "[location][lon]" => "float"
      }
    }
  }
} 
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "current_location"
        template_overwrite => true
        template => "/tmp/current-loc.json"
        document_type => "%{type}"
        document_id => "%{obd_id}"
        hosts => "MY.ELASTIC.SEARCH.IP"
    }
}
```

And my template file `current-loc.json` is as:

```
{
    "order": 0,
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "5s"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "message_field": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "analyzed",
                            "omit_norms": true,
                            "fielddata": {
                                "format": "disabled"
                            },
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match": "message",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "string_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "analyzed",
                            "omit_norms": true,
                            "fielddata": {
                                "format": "disabled"
                            },
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                                    "ignore_above": 256,
                                    "doc_values": true,
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "float_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "float"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "double_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "double"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "byte_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "byte"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "byte"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "short_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "short"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "short"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "integer_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "integer"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "long_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "long"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "date"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "date"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "geo_point_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        },
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "doc_values": true,
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "location": {
                    "doc_values": true,
                    "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "geoip": {
                    "dynamic": true,
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        },
                        "longitude": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "latitude": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "ip": {
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "type": "ip"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true,
                "omit_norms": true
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": {}
}
```

I tried almost everything available on internet. Any idea on how achieve it will be helpful. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the issue. In my template file, the value I was using was: `"template": "logstash-*"`.I was not aware that this is to notify the index on which this template is to be applied. Updating the value to `"template": "my_elastic_index"` fixed the issue.